# What gives SHA-256 its preimage resistance?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, sha-256, preimage-resistance

I was reading [some guy's description](http://www.righto.com/2014/09/mining-bitcoin-with-pencil-and-paper.html) of the [SHA-256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) algorithm and I noticed that the basic operations it uses *appear* trivial to reverse: addition, rotate bits, etc. When I say "reverse" I don't mean retrieving the exact input used to generate the hash, I mean finding some input which generates the same hash (finding a collision). I would like to understand why this is actually difficult.

> Preimage resistance: For a given *h* in the output space of the hash function, it is hard to find any message *x* with *H(x)=h*. [Source](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1173/what-are-preimage-resistance-and-collision-resistance-and-how-can-the-lack-ther)

[Here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11717/why-are-hash-functions-one-way-if-i-know-the-algorithm-why-cant-i-calculate-t) is an general explanation for why a function can be easy to calculate in *one way*, but very difficult to reverse (calculate the other way). What in particular gives SHA-256 this property? If someone tried to generate a hash collision, which obstacles would they face?

[image: SHA-256 diagram from Wikimedia commons]

The initial values for A-H are predetermined in the algorithm. The actual input comes from `W`. In this sense the "initial state" can be thought of as a combination of user input and predetermined values. Does this contribute to the difficulty in finding collisions? If the initial values for A-H could be any arbitrary values, would it be trivial to find hash collisions?

Comment: $A \oplus B = C$. Say $C = 1$, what is the value of $A$ and $B$? Now you can find both combinations, but for much larger circuits executed multiple times (multiple rounds, in other terms) this gets much harder.

Comment: [possibly related/interesting question/answers](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/30481/why-cant-i-reverse-a-hash-to-a-possible-input?rq=1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You appear to be thinking "the output of the round function appears to be a simple function of the previous round, and a word from the message; why can't we select message words to steer the output to whatever we wanted".

Well, there's something missing in the simple description you gave; message expansion.  The `W` inputs are not just directly taken from the input message; the first 16 are, but the other 48 are linear functions of the input message.  If you modify one input word, you necessarily modify a number of the `W` inputs; this effectively stops this simple steering strategy, as tweaking one `W` input (to get a desired state) will necessarily modify others (which will modify the state you're trying to set up).

This doesn't prove the SHA-256 is secure (SHA-1 does the same sort of message expansion, and we know that's weak); however it does show that this approach doesn't appear to be fruitful.

Comment: Note: The message expansion function in SHA2 family, is not linear but is a non-linear transformation, which is reason why same attacks which work against SHA1 dont work for SHA2.