# Are cryptographic hash functions quantum secure?

Tags: hash, post-quantum-cryptography

I was reading a paper related to post quantum cryptography. It says that RSA, ECC and ElGamal encryption schemes would be obsolete with the advent of quantum computers. But the hash functions can still be secure. I don't understand how one can unilaterally claim this security when hash functions themselves are not based on any hard problems. (I do have the knowledge of Merkel-Damgård and Keccak construction).

Are there hash functions considered secure just because nobody has come up with a quantum algorithm to solve it? Or are there any reduction to any well known hard problem? It there is please explain the reduction.

Comment: Hash functions have so little mathematical structure (as opposed to asymmetric crypto) that it is generally assumed that no specialized quantum algorithm exists for them (same with other symmetric algorithms).

Comment: Remember, Hash functions are a fundamentally different beast. Compare putting a book in a safe to copying the first letter of every page as proof you had the book, then burning it. The first has a way to get the book back, the second doesn't no matter how much resources you may have. A lossy algorithm is difficult to reverse beyond just being mathematically difficult, the actual data to reverse it is permanently gone.

Comment: I do not think the hardness of inverting has anything to do with lossiness, as an inverter is only require to find any valid preimage. Lossiness just adds more valid preimages, what really matters is the lack of (easily identifiable/ usable) structure.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but there is a really good answer on this site that talks about how they are difficult to solve for a valid input due to fanout (it helps to visualise the hash as a series of logic gates). With that, and the boolean satisfiability problem, I'd say they are based on hard problems?

Comment: Can you link to this answer? Regarding your remark, what matters is not being based on a hard problem, but having a polynomial time reduction to a problem that we have failed to break. The Merkle-Hellman cryptosystem was based on an NP-hard problem (the knapsack problem), but it was broken nevertheless, and its insecurity does not have any impact on the NP-hardness of the problem it was based on.

Comment: @Doddy can you link to the answer you mention in your comment by please?

Comment: @kodlu This comment on this question: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/30481/why-cant-i-reverse-a-hash-to-a-possible-input/30497#comment70632_30481

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It is a bit dubious to claim that hash functions "are not based on any hard problem": inverting a standard hash function, or finding a collision, is itself a very hard problem.

The point of a reduction is to gather the cryptanalytic effort on a smaller number of hypothesis. The fact that RSA-OAEP is CCA secure under the RSA assumption is not a proof that it is secure, simply an indication that to study its security, it suffices to study the security of the RSA problem. As many other cryptographic primitives can be reduced to the RSA assumption, it saves a considerable cryptanalytic effort.

Now, such reductions usually rely on some nice algebraic properties of mathematical hypothesis, exploiting group structure, self-randomizability, and so on. These properties are common in asymmetric cryptography, because such additional structure is already necessary in the primitives it involves. But in symmetric crypto, on the other hand, such structure is typically avoided. A consequence of that is that you need way smaller primitives (in terms of bit size) and much less computationally expensive operations to achieve a (conjectured) given security level, but you loose the possibility of reducing many symmetric primitives to a small number of hypothesis.

Still, for the most widely deployed block ciphers and hash functions, the cryptanalytic effort that has been invested on studying their security easily matches the effort invested on "generic hypothesis" such as the discrete logarithm or the factorisation, because they are widely used in practice. Therefore, there is no reason to believe that, due to the lack of reductions, inverting SHA256 should be any easier than breaking RSA. In fact, because RSA has so much structure, most experts would probably be way more surprised by an attack that inverts SHA256 than by an attack that breaks RSA. Therefore, the fact that ElGamal and the kind enjoy "reductions" does absolutely not make them more secure - it only establishes links between hardness of different primitives.

That being said, quantum computers are not magical. We cannot say anything for sure about what we can or what we cannot break with them - for all we know, it could be that $P=NP$, and that all of cryptography can be broken using a classical computer. But our current knowledge gives us some intuition on the additional power they give over classical computers. And this intuition can be summed up as follow: it seems to give some additional power, but to still fall short on solving very hard problems (say, NP-complete problems) in reasonable time.

Some problems with a special structure (factorization, discrete log) typically fall in the category of problem for which quantum computers would give a very strong speedup, because they can be reduced to the task of finding the period of some function, which seems hard to do with a classical computer, but not with a quantum one. For unstructured problems, quantum computers seem to provide some non-trivial quadratic speedup, via the use of the Grover algorithm. But a quadratic speedup does not give an attack, it simply indicates that the size of the keys should be increased by a factor two to compensate for this speedup.

Hash functions are rather unstructured, so we currently do not see how to get more than a quadratic speedup over a classical computer to attack one. Therefore, we currently conjecture that a hash function with 256 bits of classical security would still have 128 bits of quantum security. For collision resistance, quantum computers provide an even less impressive speedup: the birthday attack gives a $O(\sqrt{n})$ attack, and its quantum version seems only to make this attack $O(n^{1/3})$.

Comment: [Actually, the quantum-speed-up on collision finding is a widespread, false myth.](https://cr.yp.to/hash/collisioncost-20090517.pdf)

Comment: I did not know this article, thank you for sharing it :) If I understand right, the point is that using a quantum computer will not be as cost-effective as using massively parallel classical computers for collision-finding; I was not really looking at speed or cost, but rather at the theoretical complexity of the problem in the classical and in the quantum world. In any case, it strengthens my point and it's always nice to learn something :)

Comment: Actually, security properties of iterated hash functions often can be reduced to security properties of the used compression function. (Or in the case of sponge functions, to the properties of the used permutation.)

Comment: Sure, and it is indeed a very active research field in symmetric crypto - proving indistinguishability, indifferentiability to a random oracle, or collision-resistance of symmetric primitives built on top of "smaller" primitives. But I assumed that it was not the point of OP's question and focused on the case of the underlying fixed size input primitives.

Comment: @SEJPM I don't understand this article, if he is saying that RSA is not threatened by quantum computing what was Mr Rivest talking about in the numberphiles interview?

Comment: @daniel  This article _does not_ say that RSA is safe from quantum computers. It says that _finding collisions for hash functions like SHA-2_ can't be done faster on a quantum computer than on a classical computer.

Comment: This answer is one of the top Google hits for queries about security of hash functions against quantum cryptanalysis.  The question is specifically about _security_, not about the technical accounting of _query complexity_ that figures into part of an attack cost analysis, when all such cost analyses have put the best generic quantum collision search algorithms firmly above the best generic classical collision search algorithms—meaning the exponent $n^{1/3}$, while theoretically interesting, has no consequences for hash function collision resistance.  Could you perhaps add a note about that?

Comment: Sure, I can add a note when I get access to a computer. In general, I don't get offended when someone modifies my posts to add information, so of there is something you'd like to add, feel free to do it :)

Answer (score 8):

Common hash functions are based on combinatorial problems. Very coarsely, (future) quantum computers are claimed to be able to solve combinatorial problems with effort (at worst) $O(2^{k/2})$ for $k$ unknown bits, versus $O(2^k)$ for classical computers. Thus quantum computer do not imply the doom of security of all hashes; at worse, it implies doubling some security parameters.

I trust SHA-512 against all kinds of computers more than I trust SHA-256 against classical ones.

Answer (score -12):

A hash is just a symmetric cipher run in a loop, encrypting the input using a key also from the same input, and often with extra stuff sprinkled in as you go (e.g. prime remainders in SHA-2).

I'm no expert, but whether or not any hash is quantum-resistant boils down 
entirely to whether or not the symmetric cipher chosen for the hash is.

The SHA-2 cipher is secret (classified), so only the NSA (who invented SHA) know if it's quantum-resistant or not.

Comment: Um, how can the cipher be secret if the entire algorithm is known? Why would a hash rely on a symmetric cipher? Yes, some hashes are and symmetric ciphers and hashes have a *lot* in common, but does that mean that a hash *must* rely on an underlying block cipher?

Comment: Hi Maarten.  See Merkle–Damgård to learn up on how all modern hash mechanisms are constructed.  Once you're clear on how and why they use symmetric ciphers, you can research which one's used in SHA if you like, or if you're good at reverse engineering, maybe you can look at the SHA code and work out which one it is?  (I doubt that though - this is NSA-designed - the actual cipher they used is almost certainly classified)

Comment: Merkle–Damgård is not the only method of generating a modern hash; for instance Keccak / SHA-3 is not a Merkle–Damgård hash.

Comment: You miss the point. The Merkle–Damgård & Keccak functions are the ones needing quantum-resistance, not the output of their (repeated) applications.  You don't "brute force" a black box when you've got visibility into it's inner working of course.

Comment: This is so wrong I don't even know where to start. So, I'll limit myself to passing on the friendly advice to read up on SHA-2 as well as the  Merkle–Damgård construction it uses. Related papers are widely available to the general public and — in contrast to your claims — by no means secret or classified in any way. While doing your research, you'll soon notice there is a *huge* difference between a cipher (aka encryption algo) and a Merkle–Damgård construction. **TL;DR:** I fully agree with @MaartenBodewes' comments.

Comment: OK Fish man - tell us what symmetric cipher SHA-2 uses then.  And in case anyone reading this didn't read Snowden, also remember that part of the $52bn black NSA budget is spent on psyops.  They literally pay an army of trolls (named meme core) to spread fake news to deflect attention away from uncomfortable truths, and discredit anyone pointing them out.  Regardless of whether SHA-2 is quantum-safe or not, you should NOT be using it.  Do what all ISO standards do now: reject everything NSA - it is by definition and design untrustable.  Just like a henhouse, built by a fox.

Comment: @AnonCoward Since the cipher is only used internally in SHA-2, it does not have a name. However, when you extract it, you have a cipher called SHACAL-2, which is public. The cipher used may have been _based_ on a cipher which is classified, but the block cipher in SHA-2 is public.